# Check if a link was already visited by the user in the past

Tags: javascript

I need to check if a link was already visited or clicked by the user in the past.
I need help with the if condition, I don't know what to insert after `document.querySelector('.myclass').href`

bbcode:

```
[url=https://example.com/1 class="myclass"]Example[/url]
```

This is my incomplete javascript code:

```
if (document.querySelector('.myclass').href has been visited o clicked by the user in the past) {
    document.querySelector('.myclass').innerHTML = "You have already visited this link";
}
```

In other words, I would like to show the message `You have already visited this link` if the user has already visited or clicked the link.

**Scenario:**

it could be saved in localstorage (Same browser, same user)
Available until clear all data in the browser
Available for all users (Registered or Guest)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `This is my incomplete code` So, no code at all? It's not possible in general, that'd be a security risk, only way to do it is when the navigation is done from your own site, you'll have to explicitly track outbound clicks.

Comment: The navigation is done from my own site.
How can I explicitly track outbound clicks?

Comment: What is your actual use case here? You need to consider is this just for the current browser session or for some other period? Different browsers but same user? How mission critical is this as anything implemented by javascript is trivially bypassed? Where are you going to store the tracking information?

Comment: it could be saved in localstorage (Same browser, same user)
Available until clear all data in the browser
Available for all users (Registered or Guest)

Answer (score 0):

select all element of `a:visited:after` eg:

`$(a:visited:after).map( (index, elem) => { $(elem).html('bala bala')}`

Comment: JavaScript please, I'm not using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Querying attributes of links with the `:visited` selector is not available in current browser versions because is a privacy and security hole for all users (See https://privacylog.blogspot.com/2010/08/mozillas-css-visited-solution-is-still.html) 
In most browsers accessing properties of the current style for visited links are returning the "normal" link style and restricting the properties allowed to change in `a:visited` css declarations.

See this codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Waayyw
There is no `a:visited` links detected even if you visited the links.

Comment: Any solution using clicked instead of visited?